# 301 redirect, everything must be redirected to a specific page on the new domain

Tags: http, redirect

We need to redirect everything from an old domain to a specific page on the new domain.

Our .htaccess looks like this:
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/specific-page/

Problem is that it doesn't work. When we go to the old domain, we are redirected to http://www.example.com/ and not http://www.example.com/specific-page/

Any idea how we can fix this?

Thanks,
Louisa

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use php and redirect with the code below. Place it at the top of the index on your old domain. If you could paste the headers that would help us debug the problem.

`header("Location: http://www.example.com/specific-page/",TRUE,301);`

Comment: In index.php right? (and index.php just containing <?php + the code above + ?>)

Comment: @Louisa yes wrap it in php tags and place it at the very top of the index.php page